# AFNetworking identify reason of failure: User cancel request or network failure

Tags: ios, http, networking, request, afnetworking

I am using `AFNetworking` to make network requests. The request failure block `failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)` gets called in two scenarios,

1. When the requests fails due to network connectivity issue.
2. When I cancel the ongoing request.

In the failure block code, I am unable to differentiate between above 2 reasons. I need to differentiate to provide custom notification only when request fails due to network issue.

How to correctly identify reason for request failure?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the value of `error.code` would be equal to `NSURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet` (-1009) in scenario 1 and `NSURLErrorCancelled` (-999) in scenario 2.

Here's an example:

```
failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError* error) {                  
    if(error.code == NSURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet) {
        // handle scenario 1
    } else if(error.code == NSURLErrorCancelled) {
        // handle scenario 2
    } else {
        // handle unexpected errors
    }         
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Is that better @PeterFoti?